# De RangeIndex a DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, data

estoy analizando la serie de tiempo de una acción (histórico desde el 2000 hasta el 2018)

```
df.index
Out[179]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4309, step=1)

df.info
[4309 rows x 5 columns]>

type(df)
Out[178]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Quiero poder manejar mejor mi serie de tiempo, colocando todos los datos del tipo DatetimeIndex para poder hacer un análisis mas puntual(mensual, trimestral, etc) ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer? ¿se podrá?

Comment: Puedes crear un DateTimeIndex sin problemas pero no se si tienes una columna con las fechas o el intervalo de tiempo entre tus filas/registros al menos (¿diario sin que falte ningún día entre la fecha inicial y la final?), sin más información  difícilmente se puede dar una respuesta acertada.

Comment: Si, tengo una columna de Fechas ( en periodo diario, 4360 rows )